# The coverage problem of the button component in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[The relevant script is here]
[1](https://github.com/danqiqi1/unity)I created a button in the unity project and bound the relevant script to it, and its function can also run normally. Now I want to execute another trigger step on the game interface. When I click on a scene other than the button, the button is always executed by mistake. I didn’t find a useful solution on the Internet. Is there any way to solve this problem? ?

I have tried to limit the number of times the button is triggered, and in fact it was successful, but the layer of the button is more like covering the entire game screen. Even if I limit its execution times, it still shows that it is clicked, and the new The trigger function is still not available.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide a minima reproduceable example of the code.

Comment: Do you mean C# rather than C? Also please *include code for context*.